# What is the similar multi-line console for Firefox similar to Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

In Google Chrome when we hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open developer panel, there is a Console tab where we can enter multi-line javascript code to execute on currently opened web page - as below snapshot.

I can't find such tool in Firefox browser.

[image]

Comment: Also you have to understand that the console is not injecting code on the currently opened page, it gives you access on the javascript instance of the page. And by using the dropdown (where it say "<top frame>") you can have access on any javascript instance related to the page, like addons instance and iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firefox is the same. Just hit <kbd>F12</kbd> click on console tab, go to input panel at the bottom and paste your multi-line code.
Also using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> you change line.

[image]

Comment: I can't edit anything in Console tab of Firefox browser

Comment: I just take your answer question space to post my snapshot - please remove it whenever you don't need it.

Comment: look down... there is an input.

Comment: Oh I see that. Thanks. Hope next time you would make a screenshot using free and clean Greenshot - that would save lots of time for all of us here. Thanks a lot again!